# display another website domain template on project using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, iframe

so I had an http call using angularjs

```
$http.get(link).then(function(data, response, header) {
                                    console.log(data.data.url);
                                });
```

which is returned with an JSON body like this

```
{url:"http://www.example.com/article/1"}
```

and I want to display it to the container that I've made, let say the container is this

```
<div id="containerArticle"></div>
```

I tried it using iframe but it gives me an error `Load denied by X-Frame-Options` which is the domain is forbid me to using iframe.

my question is, what is the best approach of displaying content of another domain using angualrjs ? I've been stuck for 2 days now..

Answer (score 0):

You can consider JSONP if you are only doing Get requests.

Another approach is to create a proxy page on your server that in turn makes a request to the other domain. This is often referred to as a reverse proxy.

Comment: actually my point is to displaying the http://www.example.com/article/1 on the #containerArticle like google maps API displaying my map to the iframe I would say